# How to customize returned MYSQL dynamic table row in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have the following code, that creates a dynamic table with dynamic thead and tbody, the data is from a MySQL pivot table but displayed in a through php

```
 while($row = $res->fetch_row())
      {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($row as $cell) {
           // dd($row);
            if ($cell === NULL) { $cell = '-'; }
         
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>\n";
      }
```

I want to be able to return specific values for example the current result being returned is:

| Subject | Mark | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| English Language | 43 | Good work |
| English Literature | 59 | Good |

but I want to be able to via php make the mark color red when the student has recieved 50%, how can I doo that in the $cell variable?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement to add a class to the row, and then use CSS to make that show red.

```
while($row = $res->fetch_row())
{
    if ($row['mark'] <= 50) {
        $class = 'class="red"';
    } else {
        $class = '';
    }
    echo "<tr $class>";
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        // dd($row);
        if ($cell === NULL) { $cell = '-'; }
         
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: It is working but the array index is numerical it is not $row[mark] but it is a number that can change depending on how many colums are there in the query. How can I improve on that one?

Comment: @ZuzI well if you know what number it is, then use `$row[thatnumber]` instead, or put the value into a variable, and use `$row[$thatNmber]`. And if not - then you have to clarify what you are actually asking here.

Comment: @ZuzI You said "when the student has received 50%". I thought that was referring to the value in the `Mark` column.